# What is the default timeout for HttpURLConnection under Android?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

What is the default read and connect timeout for HttpURLConnection under android?

It's seam the default Timeout is 0, but now I m curious, is their any drawback to set the connection timeout to infinite? if something goes wrong can we have a connection that will forever wait ?

Comment: I think the default timeouts are platform dependent. But you're asking about Android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpURLConnection timeout defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199702/httpurlconnection-timeout-defaults)

Comment: @MickMnemonic: yes sorry i mean for Android

Answer (score 7):

#### A - Documentation

Due to the documentation of Java of the [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), timeout is set to 0 **(which means infinity)** by default and can be modified.

Specifically, it is written in the accessor/getter method in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getConnectTimeout());

> public int getConnectTimeout() Returns setting for connect timeout. 0
> return implies that the option is disabled (i.e., timeout of
> infinity).
>
> Returns: an int that indicates the connect timeout value in
> milliseconds Since:
> 1.5 See Also: setConnectTimeout(int), connect()

If I were you, I would set the connection timeout before starting the connection and set my logic/flow based on my own initial values. Below, you can see an example for how to get the default value and set/modify the connection timeout parameter.

#### B - Example Code

```
package com.levo.so.huc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpConnectionTimeoutDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://www.google.com/";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        
        System.out.println("Default Connection Timeout : " + con.getConnectTimeout());
        
        con.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        System.out.println("New Connection Timeout     : " + con.getConnectTimeout());

    }

}
```

#### C - Output

```
Default Connection Timeout : 0
New Connection Timeout     : 1000
```

Comment: Thanks ! i update also a little the question because i m curious to know if setting by default timeout to infinite can not lead to some problem